# result of difference in consecutive rows of column 3 in pandas provided column1 and column2 are same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Adding a column thats result of difference in consecutive rows of column 3 in pandas provided column1 and column2 are same.

```
col1 col2 
A     B      
A     B      
C     D     
C     D  
C     D
```

1st  o/p

```
col1 col2 col3_count
A     B      2
A     B      2
C     D      3
C     D      3
C     D      3
```

2nd O/P

```
ol1 col2 col3_count   diff
A     B      2        Nan
A     B      2        0
C     D      3        Nan
C     D      3        0
C     D      3        0
```

Comment: 1. Please format your code as code.
2. What are you asking? Are you trying to produce both outputs? Or do you know how to produce output 1 and are asking about output 2? And what do you mean by "result of difference in consecutive rows of column 3"?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. O/P

```
df_out = df.assign(col3_count=df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col1'].transform('size'))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  col3_count
0    A    B           2
1    A    B           2
2    C    D           3
3    C    D           3
4    C    D           3
```

## 2. O/P

```
df_out.assign(diff=df_out.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3_count'].diff())
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  col3_count  diff
0    A    B           2   NaN
1    A    B           2   0.0
2    C    D           3   NaN
3    C    D           3   0.0
4    C    D           3   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks 1st one worked but in 2nd one I am getting error and that is because of my data not the above one,will chcek it out